# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(this).find("input[name=amount]").val($(this).find("input[name=amount]").val().replace('$', ''));
```

Keep getting this error on my developer tools. I just want to replace the character $ with nothing which is ''

Thoughts?

Comment: What is $(this)? Could you provide full example somehow? E.g. at http://jsbin.com/?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your error just says that there is no element that matches your selector, so `element.val()` is returning `undefined`, which has no `replace` method. Try debugging it and `console.log()` at each step.

Also, you don't need to search for the element twice. Just store it in a variable:

```
var $input = $(this).find('input[name="amount"]');
$input.val($input.val().replace('$', ''));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Idk why, but I forgot about the console.log();