# Streaming server: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, intel-edison

I'm absolutely new to webservers and node JS and I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.dojchinovski.mk/?p=41#comment-63769) to create - and understand - a streaming server on my Intel Edison board. I already read the other posts about this problem on this website but I could not find an answer for my case

After starting the .js server I can correctly connect to it typing in my client browser [I'm using Chrome] something like: http://192.168.1.31:8888/ and a video, the same given with the tutorial, is displayed. If I want I can even activate it and it works fine

But looking to the code provided:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var reqResource = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    //console.log("Resource: " + reqResource);

    if(reqResource == "/"){

        //console.log(req.headers)
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(indexPage);
        res.end();

    } else if (reqResource == "/favicon.ico"){

        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();

    } else {

            var total;
            if(reqResource == "/movie.mp4"){
                total = movie_mp4.length;
            } else if(reqResource == "/movie.ogg"){
                total = movie_ogg.length;
            } else if(reqResource == "/movie.webm"){
                total = movie_webm.length;
            } 

            var range = req.headers.range;

            var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
            // if last byte position is not present then it is the last byte of the video file.
            var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
            var chunksize = (end-start)+1;

            if(reqResource == "/movie.mp4"){
                res.writeHead(206, { "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total, 
                                     "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                                     "Content-Length": chunksize,
                                     "Content-Type":"video/mp4"});
                res.end(movie_mp4.slice(start, end+1), "binary");

            } else if(reqResource == "/movie.ogg"){
                res.writeHead(206, { "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total, 
                                     "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                                     "Content-Length": chunksize,
                                     "Content-Type":"video/ogg"});
                res.end(movie_ogg.slice(start, end+1), "binary");

            } else if(reqResource == "/movie.webm"){
                res.writeHead(206, { "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total, 
                                     "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                                     "Content-Length": chunksize,
                                     "Content-Type":"video/webm"});
                res.end(movie_webm.slice(start, end+1), "binary");
            }
    }
}).listen(8888);
```

I think I should also be able to type in my client something like:
http://192.168.1.31:8888/movie.mp4 and solve this address correctly receiving slices of video on my chrome client. The problem is that when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
 var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/root/streaming-video-html5/streaming-video-html5/server.js:66:35)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2109:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1967:22)
```

I understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918009/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined) that this error comes from having `range.replace.split` `undefined` but why?

Any idea on how to fix this annoying problem?

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client may not be sending a `range` in the request header - it's not mandatory, so try this

```
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var start = 0, end = total - 1;
    if(range) {
        var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
        // if last byte position is not present then it is the last byte of the video file.
        end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
    }
```

I think that should fix it

Comment: your explanation was the reason of the error and your solution fixes the address problem, after that I can correctly type http://192.168.1.31:8888/movie.mp4 watching the video without the server to crash. But now loading any html page on the server like 192.168.1.31:8888/videolist.html results in an endless process, and even useless because at the end the elements are not loaded. So:
1) any idea on the reason and the fix for that?
2) is it a wrong impression of mine or when the range is not provided the streaming server works as a file server? with a 60MB video I couldn't see it

Comment: my idea would be "manually" dividing the chunks with a for cycle until the last byte, according to you does it make sense? thanks again for your time